# Display all items in an array property in Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular

I have a type script component that defines two interfaces like:

```
interface Project {
name: string;
activity: string;
lastBuildStatus: string;
lastBuildTime: string;
lastBuildLabel: string
webUrl: string;
}

interface GoArray {
projects: Array<Project>;
}
```

The components makes a call to an ASP Core controller to return an object with property 'Projects'  Which itself is a list of 'Project' objects.  So I believe this matches my interface definitions.  In the controller I set an object of type GoArray to the result from the controller

```
export class GoComponent {
public projectsArray: GoArray;

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

public getPipelineStatus(chosenUsername: string, chosenPassword: string, chosenUrl: string) {

    // debugger;
    this.http.get('api/go/cctray?username=' + chosenUsername + '&password=' + chosenPassword + '&uri=' + chosenUrl).subscribe(result => {
        this.projectsArray = result.json();
    });
```

This seems to be returning data in the format I expect.  But how do I then display all items in the array in my components HTML?

I've tried

```
<div *ngIf="projectsArray">
<div *ngFor='let project of projectsArray.projects'>
    {{project.Name}}
    {{project.Activity}}
</div>
```

Nothing gets rendered on the screen with this, but if I inspect the component using Augury, it appears as though the projectsArray is populated as I expected

[image]

How do I iterate over the list and display the properties of each of the objects?

Thanks

Comment: Your properties are lowercased, so you should display them as `{{ project.name }}` and `{{ project.activity }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
<div *ngFor='let project of projectsArray.projects'>
    {{project.name}}
    {{project.activity}}
</div>
```